# django - get() returned more than one topic

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

When I tried to relate an attribute with another one which has an **M to M** relation I received this error:

> get() returned more than one topic -- it returned 2!

Can you guys tell me what that means and maybe tell me in advance how to avoid this error ?

**models**

```
class LearningObjective(models.Model):
    learning_objective=models.TextField()

class Topic(models.Model):
    learning_objective_topic=models.ManyToManyField(LearningObjective)
    topic=models.TextField()
```

output of `LearningObjective.objects.all()`

```
[<LearningObjective: lO1>, <LearningObjective: lO2>, <LearningObjective: lO3>]
```

output of `Topic.objects.all()`

```
[<Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>, <Topic: Topic object>]
```

**views**

```
 def create_themen(request):
     new_topic=Topic(topic=request.POST['topic'])
     new_topic.save()
     return render(request, 'topic.html', {'topic': topic.objects.all()})

 def create_learning_objective(request):
     new_learning_objective=LearningObjective(learning_objective=request.POST['learning_objective'])
     new_learning_objective.save()
     new_learning_objective_topic=Topic.objects.get(topic=request.POST['topic'])
     new_learning_objective_topic.new_learning_objective_topic.add(new_learning_objective)
     return render( request, 'learning_objective.html', {
                    'topic': Topic.objects.all(),
                    'todo': TodoList.objects.all(),
                    'learning_objective': LearningObjective.objects.all()
                  })
```

Comment: Provide more code please.

Comment: that's not very useful, post the part of the code where you're using `get`. In any case, `get` is limited to 1 result, if you're making a query that matches more than one element you should use `filter`

Answer (score 208, accepted):

> `get()` returned more than one topic -- it returned 2!

The above error indicatess that you have more than one record in the DB related to the specific parameter you passed while querying using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) such as

```
Model.objects.get(field_name=some_param)
```

To avoid this kind of error in the future, you always need to do query as per your schema design.
In your case you designed a table with a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) so obviously there will be multiple records for that field and that is the reason you are getting the above error.

So instead of using `get()` you should use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) which will return multiple records. Such as

```
Model.objects.filter(field_name=some_param)
```

Please read about how to make queries in django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

Answer (score 23):

[`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) returns a single object. If there is no existing object to return, you will receive `<class>.DoesNotExist`. If your query returns more than one object, then you will get `MultipleObjectsReturned`. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) for more details about get()  queries.

> Similarly, Django will complain if more than one item matches the get() query. In this case, it will raise MultipleObjectsReturned, which again is an attribute of the model class itself.

[M2M will return any number of query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) that it is related to. In this case you can receive zero, one or more items with your query.

In your models you can us following:

```
for _topic in topic.objects.all():
    _topic.learningobjective_set.all()
```

you can use `_set` to execute a select query on M2M. In above case, you will filter all `learningObjective`s related to each topic

Answer (score 6):

Get is supposed to return, one and exactly one record, to fix this use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter), and then take first element of the queryset returned to get the object you were expecting from get, also it would be useful to check if atleast one record is returned before taking out the first element to avoid `IndexError`

Comment: Yes 
`topicresults = topic.objects.filter(topic='Thema')`
`if topicresults:`
    `topicresult = topicresults[0]`

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem and solution was `obj = ClassName.objects.filter()`

Answer (score 4):

In your `Topic` model you're allowing for more than one element to have the same `topic` field. You have created two with the same one already.

```
topic=models.TextField(verbose_name='Thema')
```

Now when trying to add a new `learningObjective` you seem to want to add it to only one `Topic` that matches what you're sending on the form. Since there's more than one with the same `topic` field `get` is finding 2, hence the exception.

You can either add the `learningObjective` to all Topics with that `topic` field:

```
for t in topic.objects.filter(topic=request.POST['Thema']):
    t.learningObjectivesTopic.add(neuesLernziel)
```

or restrict the `Topic` model to have a unique `topic` field and keep using `get`, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: okay your solution worked in both ways, the unique field of course worked but wasn't what I wanted, you were right at this point :) and the for loop is working like charm too

Answer (score 0):

To add to CrazyGeek's answer, `get` or `get_or_create` queries work only when there's one instance of the object in the database, `filter` is for two or more.

If a query can be for single or multiple instances, it's best to add an ID to the div and use an if statement e.g.

```
def updateUserCollection(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    card_id = data['card_id']
    action = data['action']

    user = request.user
    card = Cards.objects.get(card_id=card_id)

    if data-action == 'add':
        collection = Collection.objects.get_or_create(user=user, card=card)
        collection.quantity + 1
        collection.save()

    elif data-action == 'remove':
        collection = Cards.objects.filter(user=user, card=card)
        collection.quantity = 0
        collection.update()
```

Note: `.save()` becomes `.update()` for updating multiple objects. Hope this helps someone, gave me a long day's headache.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the case when you required one record but you're not having a primary key or unique to identify the object.

```
XYZ.objects.filter(model_attribute=your_value)[0]
```

This will return a normal object same as the `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **.filter** then use **.latest** selection **by pk** to get one object from filtered ones

```
tempobj = Flattable()
        try:
             tempobj = Flattable.objects.filter(org_address__icontains=row[5]).latest('pk')
        except Flattable.DoesNotExist:
             tempobj = None
```

Answer (score -1):

**Don't :-**

```
xyz = Blogs.objects.get(user_id=id)
```

**Use:-**

```
xyz = Blogs.objects.all().filter(user_id=id)
```

Comment: To improve the quality of this answer you could explain to us why your code is a better alternative and what they have done wrong. Your answer is very brief and could include at least a small sentence on how you think this is a better approach.