# Multiple Objects Returned: get() returned more than one Filter -- it returned 2

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

## views.py

import jwt,json
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from models import User
class Notemobile(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.data:
            return Response({'Error': "Please provide mobile_no"}, status="400")
        mobile_no = request.data['mobile_no']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'Error': "Invalid mobile_no"}, status="400")
        if user:
            payload = {'id': user.id,
                'mobile_no': user.mobile_no,}
            jwt_token = {'token': jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET_KEY")}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jwt_token),status=200,content_type="application/json")
        else:
            return Response(
              json.dumps({'Error': "Invalid credentials"}),
              status=400,
              content_type="application/json")

Comment: from the code you provided, it looks like there are 2 entries with same `mobile_no`.  `get()` is supposed to return 1 object. If you want to return more than 1 object, use `filter()` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django - get() returned more than one topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic)

Comment: for get method, the attribute which is passing it should be the primary key in DB. Else you can use a filter and based on length filter result you can take the decision.