# how to populate user specific data in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models employee and leave, where `Employee` is the foreign key in `Leave`. I want to display the leave requests by a specific employee on a page when they log in.
i'm not able to get the leave data populated on, and if there are more than 2 leaves applied by a single employee i get an error saying  2 items found

here is my code

`models.py`

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_leaves=models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(1),
            MaxValueValidator(24)
        ],
        default=24
    )

   def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Leave(models.Model):
    employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    start_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    end_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    req_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    STATUS_OPTIONS = (
        ("Approve","Approve"),
        ("Pending","Pending"),
        ("Decline","Decline"),
   )
    approved=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_OPTIONS,default='Pending')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.user.username

    @property
    def date_diff(self):
        return (self.start_date - self.end_date).days
```

`views.py`

```py
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    u = User.objects.get(username=user)
    e = Employee.objects.get(user=user.id)
    leave = Leave.objects.get_or_create(employee=e)
    print(leave)

    nofleaves=None
    if user.is_superuser:
        pass
    else:
        nofleaves=u.employee.no_of_leaves
    context={'nofleaves':nofleaves,'leave':leave,}

    return render(request,"leaveApp/home.html",context)
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @Jao said `get` is to fetch only one data while there is a many to one relationship between `Leave` and `Employee` that means there can be multiple Leave for one employee thus `get` will throw an error.

You should use `filter`:

Change this line

`leave = Leave.objects.get_or_create(employee=e)` to something like

```py
leave = Leave.objects.filter(employee=e.id)

if not leave.exists():
    leave = Leave.objects.create(employee=e)
```

Answer (score 2):

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic) might help.

The thing is you should use `get` for only one data. You shouldn't use `get` on a many-to-one relathionship. The logic is, there can be multiple `Leave` by `Employee` so you can't have a consistent use of `get`.

What you can use is [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) but I'd use [related names/related fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) which will allow you to use `employee.leaves` if you define it correctly.