# MultipleObjectsReturned at / get() returned more than one City -- it returned 2. No duplicates in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, get

I am new to Python and have inherited the code base from another developer. I am getting a MultipleObjectsReturned at / get() returned more than one City -- it returned 2! error.

In the code below, I changed the get to filter and checked that there are no duplicates in the database.

```
context['count_promotions'] = count_promotions = promotions.count()
    count_cities = 0
    count_products = 0
    for promotion in promotions:
        for location in promotion.store.all().values_list('city__name', 
                    flat=True).order_by('city__name').distinct('city__name'):
            count_cities += 1       
            primary_key = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=location).pk 
            province = Region.objects.filter(city__name__icontains=location)
            new_text = location.replace(',', '')
            almost_finished = new_text.replace('&', '')
            finished = almost_finished.replace(' ', '-')
            store_locations.append({
                'pk': primary_key,
                'city' : finished,
                'province' : province.name,
            })
```

What else can I check to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django - get() returned more than one topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic)

Comment: Hi @ArakkalAbu. Thanks for the link, but it does not. Any other advice for me?

Comment: Yes, it will. Its a canonical question